# PDF viewer with hyperlink preview

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, hyperlink, file-preview

When reading math papers, jumping by hyperlinks in pdf file always make me tired.

For example, "By ***Theorem 1.1*** we know that the functor is exact balabala...", in which ***Theorem 1.1*** is a hyperlink which will jump to the real Theorem 1.1 in this paper when click on it.

However, The text I'm reading is in page 400 but Theorem 1.1 may be in page 20. So after I read the fulltext of Theorem 1.1, I have to get back to page 200, by operating the scorebar or input the page number, which is not convienient enough, especially when I only need to have a glance on Theorem 1.1 instead of reading it carefully.

So if when I hover over the hyperlink, a floating small window, showing the content of the hyperlink pointing to, can popup, and can disappear when moving the mouse to somewhere else, it will be much better.

My question is, whether a pdf viewer supporting the described function or something similar exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to share a PDF reader I found recently: [Sioyek](https://github.com/ahrm/sioyek).

It's designed for academic reading, which has many useful functions, including hover-preview.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe the coincidence that you answered to this thread as soon as I found it.

Answer (score 6):

- For Linux: [Evince / GNOME Document Viewer](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince), at least from version 3.38.0.
- For macOS: [Skim](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io/).
- For Windows, macOS and Linux: [Sioyek](https://sioyek.info/) (from [Yijun Yuan’s answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/83132/)).

Comment: Since a long time I have been looking for a PDF reader that can display the corresponding reference when hovering the mouse over a citation. Skim does exactly that! It's surprising that this app is not popular (even in the academic community). Thanks a lot! @yijun-yuan Thanks for your question as well!